# Error in sentence

Tags: relative-pronouns, ellipsis

> *I hope this date will not pose any problems to your schedule.*

The sentence above is an announcement of an event. So in order to proofread this sentence, I used proofreadbot.com,which showed a number of errors in my sentence.

1. 1.It showed that there is punctuation error thereby suggesting to add 'that' after hope.
2. Similary, it showed an error in the use of 'not', citing lack of assertiveness.
3. It showed an error in tense. I know that I have used present and future tense but I don't think that's an error, is it?
4. The use of first and second person. It told me not to use first and second person in formal writing. Here I have used 'yours'.

I want to know whether they are really errors or not. And I also want suggestion on improving my sentences if I have made any errors.

Comment: Proofread websites or softwares are a "child's play", in my opinion. Never use them at all, trusting them is unimaginable :) Your sentence is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

Your sentence is perfectly alright.  One can play about with English all day, but what you've written is what I would have written; for one thing it has a slightly less formal feel to it which is good.